# Keep search value entered in datatable when page is refreshed vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datatable, filtering

How to keep the values filtered in the page after refresh. [image]Keep filtered items populated with the last selected values when I route back to this view.

```
<vk-datatable
            :columns="columns"
            :rows="filteredProducts"
            :per_page="8"
            :actions="actions"
            v-on:row_click="rowClick"
            v-on:row_delete="rowDelete"
            v-on:row_edit="rowClick"
            v-if="filteredProducts"
            :loadingPropData="$apollo.queries.products.loading"
        ></vk-datatable>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a regular page reload, then you just need to use models on inputs and save the entered values to local storage (for example).
On page load, insert values from local storage into each model in the create hook.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html (for the select input the same)

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <input v-model="userName"
               @input.trim="handleInput('userName', $event)"/>
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'ComponentName',
        data: () => ({
            userName: null
        }),
        methods: {
            handleInput(key, {target}) {
                const storageData = {[key]: target.value};

                localStorage.setItem('storageKey', JSON.stringify(storageData));
            },

            /* with debounce */
            handleInput2: _.debounce(function (key, {target}) {
                const storageData = {[key]: target.value};

                localStorage.setItem('storageKey', JSON.stringify(storageData));
            }, 500),
        },
        created() {
            this.userName = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storageKey')) || {}).userName; // value or null
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for helping out, my issue is that I can't access the search filter value because it's in a vk datatable

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) and to [keep-alive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components)

Comment: Im kinda new to vue.js can you suggest a way to implement this please.